# Generate sample project configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration, configuration-files

I'm working on a package that has a cli component from which you can start a new project. This newly created project would heavily rely on a variety of configuration, docker, and other files. I'd like to have a cli command, say, `myproject init` that creates a new directory, and copies a variety of files in it, making the user's life easier.

Now, the project itself is pip-installable, so every file I add to the project will be located somewhere in the `site-packages` directory. Adding those sample config files to the project doesn't seem like a good option, since finding them where the project has been installed pretty hard.

The best solution I've found far is adding the configuration to python files as strings:

```
INIT_FILE_MODEL_TEMPLATE = """---
version: 1

kind: experiment

logging:
  level: INFO

model:
  # set you model
"""
```

and then dumping them to actual files when the init command is called.

Are there any better options to this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to what "django-admin startproject mysite"  does but for a command line utility development in python?

Comment: I don't know too well how django works but at a first glance yes, it's something similar. Basically creating some boilerplate functionality and configuration

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution until a better one pops up:

1. Include any config files in the package under some directory `project/project_template`
2. Ship package using `include_package_data=True` in the `setup()` method
3. Use `pkgutil.get_data` to get the contents of those files:

   ```
   import pkgutil
   data = pkgutil.get_data('project', 'project_template/config.dat')
   ```
4. Create new directory and copy over the files of interest to newly created directory